# Unable to declare multiple custom named properties TypeScript MUI v5 Palette

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to setup many custom attributes to keep things semantically easy to update in the future. However I am having issues with having more than just one custom property in MUI v5

### Ts Error

```
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property 'background' must be of type 'TypeBackground', but here has type 'PaletteColor'.
```

### palette.ts

```
export const palette = {
  primary: {
    light: '#6D6B8C',
    main: '#6514DD',
    dark: '#6D6B8C',
  },
  secondary: {
    main: '#6D6B8C',
  },
  error: {
    main: '#bd4646',
  },
  background: {
    main: '#fff',
    paper: '#F5F5F5',
  },
  border: {
    main: '#DADAE1',
    primary: '#DADAE1',
  },
  text: {
    primary: '#6D6B8C',
    secondary: '#000',
  },
}


declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Palette {
    border: Palette['primary']
    background: Palette['primary']
  }

  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface PaletteOptions {
    border?: PaletteOptions['primary']
    background?: PaletteOptions['primary']
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you create a [codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io/) so I could reproduce?

Comment: humm well I've embarrassed myself: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-bartik-bmz8x?file=/src/App.tsx... Its working!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a feature of TypeScript called *declaration merging*. The problem is because non-function members of the interfaces should be unique. If they are not unique, they must be of the same type (see [docs here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces)).

A quick aside: Using `declare module 'foo'` to import and merge existing objects is called *module augmentation*, which is a special type of declaration merging. You can actually merge two interfaces with the same name in the same file.

---

### A Possible Solution

Since it's not possible to merge two members of different types with declaration merging, an alternative could be to simply declare a new type.

```js
/// animal.ts
export interface Animal {
  name: string
  age: number
  birthday: string // goal: represent birthday as a `Date` instead of `string`
}


/// pet.ts
import { Animal } from './animal'

// remove the offending property from `Animal`, while simultaneously
// extending the new `Pet` type to add `birthday` back in as a `Date`
type Pet = Omit<Animal, 'birthday'> & {
  birthday: Date
  ownerId: number
}

// the compiler accepts the augmented definition of `Pet`
const pet: Pet = {
  name: 'fido',
  age: 2,
  birthday: new Date(), // see, not a string!
  ownerId: 1
}
```

### Explanation

Since `declare module` adds extra noise, I'll leave it out to make the example more intuitive. Consider the following code snippet:

```js
/// animal.ts - good
export interface Animal {
  name: string
  age: number
}

export interface Animal {
  birthday: string
}
```

The above code is completely allowed in TypeScript. The compiler merges the two separate declarations of `Animal` into a single definition.

Let's look at a different example.

```js
/// animal.ts - bad
export interface Animal {
  name: string
  age: number
  birthday: string
}

export interface Animal {
  birthday: Date
}
```

Hopefully, the problem is obvious. Both declarations of `Animal` have `birthday`, but of different types. How is the compiler supposed to know what type `birthday` should be? It could make some assumptions, but thankfully it does't, instead preferring to give an error:

```
typescript: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property 'birthday' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'Date'.
```