# Typescript error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

When I am developing on local host typescript build works fine. but when using docker and node image, when I want to build, it generates this strange error:

```
src/middlewares/auth.ts(16,13): error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.
Property 'user' must be of type 'UserModel', but here has type 'UserModel'.
```

what is the problem with `UserModel` here?

```js
// auth.ts
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { UserModel } from '../models/user.model';
import { Resp } from '../utils/Response';
import { AuthErrEnum } from '../enums/auth/auth-message.enum';

const authService = new AuthService();
const userService = new UserService();

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            user: UserModel;
        }
    }
}

export async function authMiddleware(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {

    const authorization = req.headers.authorization;
    if(!authorization) return Resp.error(AuthErrEnum.NO_TOKEN_PROVIDED,401).send(res)

    const token = authorization.split(' ')[1];
    if(!token) {
        return Resp.error(AuthErrEnum.NO_TOKEN_PROVIDED, 401).send(res)
    }

    let payload;
    try{
        payload = await authService.decodeToken(token);
    } catch(err) {
        return Resp.error(AuthErrEnum.INVALID_TOKEN, 401).send(res)  
    }    
    
    const user = await userService.findWithRelations(payload.id);
     
    req.user = user;

    next();
}
```

```
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev src/app.ts",
    "start": "node build/app.js",
    "build": "del build/* && tsc",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.10.3",
    "del-cli": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

```
// tsconfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "ES2018",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./build/",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,      /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "nginx",
    "ecosystem.config.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Weird. Does building regularly then running the program work? If so, then there's something wrong in your Dockerfile.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue, did you find the clue ?

Comment: @YouneL I deleted ```node_modules``` and ```build``` directory. I was using ```sequelize``` as ORM for database and I changed it's version to ```"sequelize": "^6.6.2"``` that I was using in another project. I also deleted my docker image and volumes. finally the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Use Go To Definition on UserModel and make sure that all declarations have the same type signature. In other words, make sure that every declaration of a property is of type boolean or extends boolean. That applies to generic types on methods as well, for some odd reason. Apparently you can't specify a new generic overload with extra generics.

This answer may also give additional clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73071602/258482